# How to create an overlay window to show over all apps on Android 10

Tags: java, android, android-studio, service, overlay

Hi everyone I know others tried to do some similar things, but all I can find is old and doesn't seem to work for me on Android 10.

What I want to do is actually an overlay that looks a little bit like "Show CPU stats" feature in some custom ROMs dev-options. Here's what I mean:

[image: cpu stats overlay]
.

I have a kernel app and I want to show an overlay like this showing kernel stats like cpu and gpu freqs. Code for cpu and gpu freqs is not a problem.

I actually want to know how to create an overlay. Here's what I tried so far from tutorials I found online, but every tutorial I try I get the same error:
`Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?`

Here's what I use in manifest.xml:

```js
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<application>...
...
...
    <service android:name="org.pierre2324.nogravity.HUD"/>
</application>
```

Here's my fragment which contains a toggle to enable the overlay (HUD) service:

```js
public class MainFragment9 extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "MainFragment9";
    private Switch overandroidlaySwitch;

    @Nullable
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment9, container, false);

        overlaySwitch = (Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.overlay_toggle);

//region HUD SWITCH
        overlaySwitch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (overlaySwitch.isChecked()) {
                    //Start the service
                    if(!isSystemAlertPermissionGranted(MainFragment9.this.getActivity())){
                        requestSystemAlertPermission(MainFragment9.this.getActivity(),1);
                    }
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
                        MainFragment9.this.getActivity().getApplicationContext().startForegroundService(new Intent(MainFragment9.this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), HUD.class));
                    } else {
                        MainFragment9.this.getActivity().startService(new Intent(MainFragment9.this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), HUD.class));
                    }
                    newEditor.putBoolean("Overlay", true);
                    Toast.makeText(MainFragment9.this.getActivity() ,"NGK Overlay enabled!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    //Stop the service
                    MainFragment9.this.getContext().stopService(new Intent(getContext(), HUD.class));
                    newEditor.putBoolean("Overlay", false);
                    Toast.makeText(MainFragment9.this.getContext(), "NGK Overlay disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                newEditor.apply();
            }
        });
//endregion

        return view;
    }
}
```

And finally here's my HUD service:

```js
public class HUD extends Service{

    private View topLeftView;

    private Button overlayedButton;
    private WindowManager wm;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

        topLeftView = new View(this);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams topLeftParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        topLeftParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
        topLeftParams.x = 0;
        topLeftParams.y = 0;
        topLeftParams.width = 0;
        topLeftParams.height = 0;
        wm.addView(topLeftView, topLeftParams);                       //Crashes here...
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (overlayedButton != null) {
            wm.removeView(overlayedButton);
            wm.removeView(topLeftView);
            overlayedButton = null;
            topLeftView = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks again for your help!

**EDIT:**

I got the overlay to work using a separate xml file for the overlay itself and with following code:

```js
public class HUD extends Service{

    static final String CHANNEL_ID = "Overlay_notification_channel";

    private static final int LayoutParamFlags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED;

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Display mDisplay;
    private View layoutView;
    private WindowManager windowManager;
    private WindowManager.LayoutParams params;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                LayoutParamFlags,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.END;
        windowManager = (WindowManager) this.getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        mDisplay = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        layoutView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ngk_overlay, null);
        windowManager.addView(layoutView, params);

//This is needed to keep the service running in background just needs a notification to call with startForeground();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, getString(R.string.ngk_overlay_notification), NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            notificationChannel.setSound(null, null);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
            Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID);
            builder.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.ngk_overlay)).setContentText(getString(R.string.ngk_overlay_notification)).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_mono2);
            startForeground(1, builder.build());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        windowManager.removeView(layoutView);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, you said in your edit that you were able to make the overlay work. I tried to replicate the code but I wasn't able to make it work. Would it be possible to know if this approach still works as of now? Also, if it still works, could you share the xml of the layout of the overlay (the one you inflate)?

Comment: I actually managed to solve it, your solution works, the only problem is that if the application is not installed through the play store, the "draw over other apps"  permission is not automatically granted. To fix it you just have to go into the android settings, search for your application and manually grant the requested permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the service to the manifest like this?

```
<service android:name="com.xxx.xxx.HUD">
</service>
</application>
```

Or maybe try WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE (but i think thats just for older api's).

Edit:
Also, try to get the context/activity different.

> MainFragment9.this.getActivity().getApplicationContext()
>   and
>   MainFragment9.this.getActivity()

doesn't seem very good.
Declare the Activity object outside of the methods.
Something more like this (untested pseudo code):

```
...
private Switch overandroidlaySwitch;
private Activity myActivity;
    @Nullable
    public View onCreateView
    myActivity = getActivity();
```

Comment: yea sorry I did in manifest:
```
        <service android:name="org.pierre2324.nogravity.HUD"/>
```

Comment: So I changed to TYPE_PHONE:
WindowManager.LayoutParams topLeftParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

Comment: And service start changed to:
private Activity myActivity;
myActivity = getActivity();

myActivity.startForegroundService(new Intent(myActivity, HUD.class));

but still crashes:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service org.pierre2324.nogravity.HUD: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?

Comment: my Window Manager (wm) seems null